# Getting openldap + postgres working

Tags: ldap, postgresql, openldap

I'm having an issue configuring openldap v2.4.46 + postgres (9.6.x), I'm running into a problem i cannot find an answer to.

**Installation steps**

```
yum install -y vim libacl-devel libblkid-devel gnutls-devel readline-devel python-devel autoconf gcc-c++ gcc glibc-devel glibc-headers kernel-headers libgomp libstdc++-devel openssl-devel e2fsprogs-devel keyutils-libs-devel krb5-devel libselinux-devel libsepol-devel libtool-ltdl-devel postgresql-odbc.x86_64 postgresql-client wget postgresql-devel librpcsecgss unixODBC-devel
export HISTCONTROL=erasedups:ignorespace
export HISTSIZE=""
wget ftp://ftp.openldap.org/pub/OpenLDAP/openldap-release/openldap-2.4.46.tgz
tar xvf openldap-2.4.46.tgz
cd openldap-2.4.46 && ./configure --prefix=/ --enable-sql --without-cyrus-sasl --disable-bdb --enable-crypt --disable-hdb && make depend && make && make install && cd -

psql -h postgres -U postgres -c 'DROP DATABASE ldap'
psql -h postgres -U postgres -c 'CREATE DATABASE ldap'
cat /openldap-2.4.46/servers/slapd/back-sql/rdbms_depend/pgsql/backsql_create.sql | psql -h postgres -U postgres ldap
```

*/etc/openldap/slap.conf*

```
include     /etc/openldap/schema/core.schema 
include     /etc/openldap/schema/cosine.schema
include     /etc/openldap/schema/nis.schema
include     /etc/openldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema
include     /etc/openldap/schema/ppolicy.schema

pidfile     /var/run/slapd.pid
argsfile    /var/run/slapd.args

database        sql
suffix         "dc=my-domain,dc=com"
rootdn         "cn=Manager,dc=my-domain,dc=com"
rootpw          secret
dbname          ldap
dbuser          postgres
dbpasswd        postgres
insentry_stmt  "insert into ldap_entries (id,dn,oc_map_id,parent,keyval) values ((select max(id)+1 from ldap_entries),?,?,?,?)"
upper_func      "upper"
strcast_func    "text"
concat_pattern  "?||?"
has_ldapinfo_dn_ru      no

lastmod off
```

*/etc/odbc.ini*

```
;  odbc.ini
;
[ODBC Data Sources]
ldap=PostgreSQL

[ldap]
; WARNING: The old psql odbc driver psqlodbc.so is now renamed psqlodbcw.so
; in version 08.x. Note that the library can also be installed under an other
; path than /usr/local/lib/ following your installation.
Driver=/usr/lib64/psqlodbcw.so
Description=Connection to LDAP/POSTGRESQL
Servername=postgres
Port=5432
Protocol=6.4
FetchBufferSize=99
Username=postgres
Password=postgres
Database=ldap
ReadOnly=no
Debug=1
CommLog=1

[ODBC]
InstallDir=/usr/local/lib
```

**Running the app**

```
$ /usr/libexec/slapd -f /etc/openldap/slapd.conf -d 3
```

---

*group.ldif*

```
dn: dc=my-domain,dc=com
objectClass: domain
dc: my-domain 

dn: ou=people,dc=my-domain,dc=com
ou: people
objectClass: organizationalUnit

dn: ou=groups,dc=my-domain,dc=com
ou: groups
objectClass: organizationalUnit
```

**Problem**

```
$ ldapadd -f groups.ldif -h localhost -D "cn=Manager,dc=my-domain,dc=com" -w secret
adding new entry "dc=my-domain,dc=com"
ldap_add: Server is unwilling to perform (53)
    additional info: operation not permitted within namingContext
```

**Debug from the server**

```
5afc9875 slap_listener_activate(6): 
5afc9875 >>> slap_listener(ldap:///)
5afc9875 connection_get(10): got connid=1000
5afc9875 connection_read(10): checking for input on id=1000
ber_get_next
ldap_read: want=8, got=8
  0000:  30 30 02 01 01 60 2b 02                            00...`+.          
ldap_read: want=42, got=42
  0000:  01 03 04 1e 63 6e 3d 4d  61 6e 61 67 65 72 2c 64   ....cn=Manager,d  
  0010:  63 3d 6d 79 2d 64 6f 6d  61 69 6e 2c 64 63 3d 63   c=my-domain,dc=c  
  0020:  6f 6d 80 06 73 65 63 72  65 74                     om..secret        
ber_get_next: tag 0x30 len 48 contents:
5afc9875 op tag 0x60, time 1526503541
ber_get_next
ldap_read: want=8 error=Resource temporarily unavailable
5afc9875 conn=1000 op=0 do_bind
ber_scanf fmt ({imt) ber:
ber_scanf fmt (m}) ber:
5afc9875 >>> dnPrettyNormal: <cn=Manager,dc=my-domain,dc=com>
5afc9875 <<< dnPrettyNormal: <cn=Manager,dc=my-domain,dc=com>, <cn=manager,dc=my-domain,dc=com>
5afc9875 do_bind: version=3 dn="cn=Manager,dc=my-domain,dc=com" method=128
5afc9875 ==>backsql_bind()
5afc9875 conn=1000 op=0: rootdn="cn=Manager,dc=my-domain,dc=com" bind succeeded
5afc9875 <==backsql_bind(0)
5afc9875 do_bind: v3 bind: "cn=Manager,dc=my-domain,dc=com" to "cn=Manager,dc=my-domain,dc=com"
5afc9875 send_ldap_result: conn=1000 op=0 p=3
5afc9875 send_ldap_response: msgid=1 tag=97 err=0
ber_flush2: 14 bytes to sd 10
ldap_write: want=14, written=14
  0000:  30 0c 02 01 01 61 07 0a  01 00 04 00 04 00         0....a........    
5afc9875 connection_get(10): got connid=1000
5afc9875 connection_read(10): checking for input on id=1000
ber_get_next
ldap_read: want=8, got=8
  0000:  30 49 02 01 02 68 44 04                            0I...hD.          
ldap_read: want=67, got=67
  0000:  13 64 63 3d 6d 79 2d 64  6f 6d 61 69 6e 2c 64 63   .dc=my-domain,dc  
  0010:  3d 63 6f 6d 30 2d 30 17  04 0b 6f 62 6a 65 63 74   =com0-0...object  
  0020:  43 6c 61 73 73 31 08 04  06 64 6f 6d 61 69 6e 30   Class1...domain0  
  0030:  12 04 02 64 63 31 0c 04  0a 6d 79 2d 64 6f 6d 61   ...dc1...my-doma  
  0040:  69 6e 20                                           in                
ber_get_next: tag 0x30 len 73 contents:
5afc9875 op tag 0x68, time 1526503541
ber_get_next
ldap_read: want=8 error=Resource temporarily unavailable
5afc9875 conn=1000 op=1 do_add
ber_scanf fmt ({m) ber:
ber_scanf fmt ({m{W}}) ber:
ber_scanf fmt ({m{W}}) ber:
ber_scanf fmt (}) ber:
5afc9875 >>> dnPrettyNormal: <dc=my-domain,dc=com>
5afc9875 <<< dnPrettyNormal: <dc=my-domain,dc=com>, <dc=my-domain,dc=com>
5afc9875 ==>backsql_add("dc=my-domain,dc=com")
5afc9875 oc_check_required entry (dc=my-domain,dc=com), objectClass "domain"
5afc9875 oc_check_allowed type "objectClass"
5afc9875 oc_check_allowed type "dc"
5afc9875 oc_check_allowed type "structuralObjectClass"
5afc9875    backsql_add("dc=my-domain,dc=com"): cannot map structuralObjectClass "domain" -- aborting
5afc9875 send_ldap_result: conn=1000 op=1 p=3
5afc9875 send_ldap_response: msgid=2 tag=105 err=53
ber_flush2: 58 bytes to sd 10
ldap_write: want=58, written=58
  0000:  30 38 02 01 02 69 33 0a  01 35 04 00 04 2c 6f 70   08...i3..5...,op  
  0010:  65 72 61 74 69 6f 6e 20  6e 6f 74 20 70 65 72 6d   eration not perm  
  0020:  69 74 74 65 64 20 77 69  74 68 69 6e 20 6e 61 6d   itted within nam  
  0030:  69 6e 67 43 6f 6e 74 65  78 74                     ingContext        
5afc9875 <==backsql_add("dc=my-domain,dc=com"): 53 "operation not permitted within namingContext"
5afc9875 connection_get(10): got connid=1000
5afc9875 connection_read(10): checking for input on id=1000
ber_get_next
ldap_read: want=8, got=7
  0000:  30 05 02 01 03 42 00                               0....B.           
ber_get_next: tag 0x30 len 5 contents:
5afc9875 op tag 0x42, time 1526503541
ber_get_next
ldap_read: want=8, got=0

5afc9875 ber_get_next on fd 10 failed errno=0 (Success)
5afc9875 conn=1000 op=2 do_unbind
5afc9875 connection_close: conn=1000 sd=10
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out i was expecting `sql` to work similarly to `mdb` and.. it does not. Every relation needs to be defined now inside the db; kiss your `import ....ldif` goodbye and now add them into the db.

```
psql -h postgres -U postgres -c 'DROP DATABASE ldap'
psql -h postgres -U postgres -c 'CREATE DATABASE ldap'
psql -h postgres -U postgres ldap < /openldap-2.4.46/servers/slapd/back-sql/rdbms_depend/pgsql/backsql_create.sql
psql -h postgres -U postgres ldap < /openldap-2.4.46/servers/slapd/back-sql/rdbms_depend/pgsql/testdb_create.sql
psql -h postgres -U postgres ldap < /openldap-2.4.46/servers/slapd/back-sql/rdbms_depend/pgsql/testdb_metadata.sql
psql -h postgres -U postgres ldap < /openldap-2.4.46/servers/slapd/back-sql/rdbms_depend/pgsql/testdb_data.sql
```

for me this was more trouble than it was worth, so ive since abandoned this approach and have just gone with `mdb`.

If there is anyone out there that has a better way of doing this, please! I'm all ears.